# pass random numbers generated from Rand() to other pages for verification

Tags: php, html, forms, random

I am trying to get a way to get the phone number of the users on my website verified. to do that I am integrating an SMS gateway. this will work like this:-

step 1 /page 1 - User clicks on a button to get their phone number verified. Which runs the script that sends an SMS to their phone number with a random number and re-directs the user to page 2. Please see code below:-

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="sms2" name="sms2" method="POST" action="sms3.php">
     <table width= "400">

       <tr>
         <td align="right" valign="top">Verification Code:</td>
         <td align="left"><textarea name="Vefificationcode" cols="80" rows="20" id="Vefificationcode"></textarea></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" name= "submit" value="submit"/>
         </td>
         <p>
           <?php
             $_SESSION['phverf'] = rand();//set the session variable
             $phverf= rand();//stores the value of rand function in phverf variable
             echo "$phverf" . "\n"; // echo this just to check...when users inputs the random number received on sms
            ?>
         </p>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </form>


  </body>
</html>
```

step2/ Page2 - has an input box for the user to type in the same verification code they received in SMS. and hit submit. They go to the 3rd Page. Please see code below:-

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

    <?php
      echo $_SESSION['phverf'];
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

         $verificationcode= $_POST['Vefificationcode'];
         echo $verificationcode;

         if($_SESSION['phverf']==$verificationcode){echo"you have successfully verified your Phone Number";}
          else {echo "Please type in the code sent to your phone number correctly";}
       }
       ?>

   </body>
</html>
```

Thanks 
Pranay

Comment: my issue is that on step 3 page 3 the random number generated by Rand() gets refreshed and hence it never matches to what was sent on SMS. i have tried using session variables as you can see but doesn't seem to resolve... Please help!!

Answer (score -1):

Add a column to set flag for the verified users.

> EG: `number_verified = 0` if the number is not verified 
>   and set to `number_verified = 1` if verified, 
>   set default to 0.

Add another column to store the random number. I recommend to store in table, this makes you to validate easily !
If the user click the verify number, then you redirect the page to send SMS, meanwhile you store the random number in the users table.
If the user entered the verification code compare it with the random number you stored in the table and set the `number_verified = 1`. Hope its helps you !

Comment: i added a in my database and tried again but get an error  "! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'VALUE' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\L\sms2.php on line 14"
 :-  <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = INSERTINTO %_dbnamer (phoneverificationcode)
VALUE($phverf);

?>
?></p>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: can you post the error code, the above code is not clear !

Comment: which one is line 14 ?

Comment: ` INSERT INTO tablename (fieldname) VALUES('value');`

Comment: $sql = INSERTINTO %_dbnamer (phoneverificationcode) VALUES ($phverf); ?>

Comment: `INSERT INTO` write with spaces. Also what is that %_bdnamer ?

Comment: The new string is like this :-$sql = "INSERT INTO dbname (`phoneverificationcode`)
VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$phverf)."')";  basically i added the mysqli escape string and it does store the value , but this brings more issue,if i go back it gives me an error "Duplicate field '0' for key 'PRIMARY'"