# match user input in HTML Form with data in MY SQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to setup a phone number verification system on my website. and the logic i am using is :-

1) User clicks a button which says get phone number verification done.( a script runs which sends an SMS with a random number which is generated using Rand (). This number also gets stored in that users row in the database.

```
  <html>
        <head>
        </head>
           <body>
             <form id="sms2" name="sms2" method="POST" action="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=83">
              <table width= "400">

                 <tr>
                   <td align="right" valign="top">Verification Code:</td>
                   <td align="left"><textarea name="veficationcode" cols="82" rows="5" id="veficationcode"></textarea></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td colspan="4" align="right"><input type="submit" name= "submit" value="submit"/>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
                </table>
              </form>

            </body>
    </html>



<?php


Global $_CB_framework;

$myId = $_CB_framework->myId();
$cbUser =& CBuser::getInstance( $myId );

if ( ! $cbUser ) {
 $cbUser =& CBuser::getInstance( null );
}

$user =& $cbUser->getUserData();

echo$myId;
        $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "UPDATE tablename SET phoneverificationcode ='$phverf'
    WHERE id = $myId";


    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

2) The user is re-directed to a page where he enters the verification code he received on sms and hits submit once he does that. script runs and grabs data from that users row in database and matches it with what he entered. If it matches he gets a success message else he gets an error message.

```
<?php

Global $_CB_framework;

$myId = $_CB_framework->myId();
$cbUser =& CBuser::getInstance( $myId );

if ( ! $cbUser ) {
 $cbUser =& CBuser::getInstance( null );
}

$user =& $cbUser->getUserData();

echo$myId;
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $verificationcode = $_POST["veficationcode"]; 
    echo "verificationcode".$verificationcode;

    $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";

    // Create connection
    $connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$connect) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    //select the data from the database for the users own row based on his unique id
    $query = "SELECT phoneverificationcode FROM tablename WHERE id=$myId";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
    echo $row[0];

    if($verificationcode == $row){echo "SUCCESS!!!";}

    else{
    echo "verification code mismatch". "Please try again.";

    }
    $connect->close();
    }
    ?>
```

The issue I am facing is that it always says that there is a mismatch. Not sure what I am missing here ?

Comment: the issue i am facing is that it always says that there is a mismatch. Need help please... not sure what i am missing here ?

Comment: Edit your question to include the actual issue, don't add it in the comments. - And where are you setting `$myId`?

Comment: Match `$row[0]` not only `$row` at `$verificationcode == $row`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass random numbers generated from Rand() to other pages for verification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469171/pass-random-numbers-generated-from-rand-to-other-pages-for-verification)

Comment: it looks like $phverf/$myId appears to be undefined...if you check your database, is your data actually being stored?  please edit your post with more code and you could also update your code formatting too.

Comment: @pranay what exactly you want ? or please mention issue which you are facing

Comment: @Epodax- actually i am getting the value of that Variable from another components API, i have not included that code as if i eco id it displays so that is not an issue .I have removed that code as to not confuse people.

Comment: @Saty I tried to change $row to $row[0] but still the same :-  verificationcode23872verification code mismatchPlease try again. (in this the first part verification and the number is being echoed from user input in last page. similarly i have echoed $row[0], which is not echoing out , i am echoing out both these to one page to see if the values are indeed matching .

Comment: It seems as if your issue lies on the value of $myId...if you can also include how you define or set the value of $myId...done

Comment: @ Clayton & William i have now added the API call for Community builder api fromwhere i am getting the ID of the logged in user and when i eco it out it displays correctly for that particular user , so i know id id not the issue as it matches with their id in DB table too.

Comment: @pradeepyou are correct that post was to use Rand over HTML forms without DB query, but your suggestion seemed to work till where i am able to insert the random number in that users row in the user table but in retrieval there is an issue as it doesn't echo out the retrieval value not it matches

Comment: @user1140237 while retrieving the random code stored in db it is not working as i am unable to echo out the code to the screen nor am i able to get the database value to match with the code input by the user in step 1 HTML form where he hits submit.

Comment: any suggestions on what i am missing on step 2 in retrieval from the db?

Comment: made some changes and it takes me a step further pease note the changes in the script in step 2 :- $query = "SELECT `phoneverificationcode` FROM `tablename` WHERE `id`= $myId";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
echo "db queryresult=".$row['phoneverificationcode'];
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
if($verificationcode == $row['phoneverificationcode']){echo "SUCCESS!!!";} i echo both the customer input and the query result they match with exact same values the If statement gives a verification codemismatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i put the if statement in the while loop which resolved this issue. `if ($result = mysqli_query($connect,$query)) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){if($row["cb_phoneverificationcode"] == $row["cb_userinputphonecode"]){ echo "SUCCESS!!!"; }

else{ echo "verification code mismatch. Please try again";}
}`

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to check against the `phoneverificationcode` which is the field name in the DB itself, Change your `If-Statement` to :

```
  if($verificationcode == $row['phoneverificationcode']){echo "SUCCESS!!!";}

                    else{
                    echo "verification code mismatch". "Please try again.";

                    }
```

Comment: i edited , but it still behaves the same way and displays verification code mismatch....   i have also inserted an echo statement to see what DB value it is retrieving but the echo is not displaying anything                   echo $row['phoneverificationcode'];

Comment: now when i changed the code to :-  step 2 :- $query = "SELECT phoneverificationcode FROM tablename WHERE id= $myId"; $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query); if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) echo "db queryresult=".$row['phoneverificationcode']; } else { echo "0 results"; } if($verificationcode == $row['phoneverificationcode']){echo "SUCCESS!!!";} i echo both the customer input and the query result they match with exact same values the If statement gives a verification codemismatch . only IF statement is failing ??

Comment: now the issue is that with the if statement it always give a success even if the value is not matching, i have altered the code as i have to resolve this  :-  if($row['cb_userinputphonecode'] === $row['cb_phoneverificationcode'] ){echo "SUCCESS!!!";}
else { echo "verification code mismatch. Please try again";}

Comment: Okay...Please try again with just two equal signs... '==' and not '===' ... And can you please post your select statement...done

Comment: still the same with == , $query = "SELECT `cb_userinputphonecode`,`cb_phoneverificationcode`FROM `t4qcm_comprofiler` WHERE `id`=$myId";   i have also echoed and doen Var_dump, and the echo displays the cell values correctly but Var_dump() displays null hence they are showing as always matching even when the values dont match due to incorrect user input

Comment: This is the result of the query :- I am including the details of what each of these data means / represents in brackets next to them :- (This is the value of $myId)849   (This is the cb_userinputphonecode value retrieved from db)Post10  (This is the cb_phoneverificationcode value retrieved from db )10721
null (vardump of 4
null
SUCCESS!!!

Comment: After $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query); please do echo print_r($row); and post the output...done

Comment: This is the result of the query :- I am including the details of what each of these data means / represents in brackets next to them :- (This is the value of $myId)849   (This is the cb_userinputphonecode value retrieved from db)Post10  (This is the cb_phoneverificationcode value retrieved from db )10721
null (vardump of cb_userinputphonecode)
null (cb_phoneverificationcode)
SUCCESS!!! (output of If statement see how it is displaying success even when the echo values are not matching but Var_dump values match)

Comment: Alter your if-statement and put it like this:  if($row['cb_userinputphonecode'] == $row['cb_phoneverificationcode']){
    echo "SUCCESS!!! With values - User Input : ".$row['cb_userinputphonecode']." And Phone Verification : ".$row['cb_phoneverificationcode'];
   }else{
       echo "verification code mismatch. Please try again";                
   }

Comment: 849Post4870New record created successfully4870
null
null
SUCCESS!!! With values - User Input : And Phone Verification :

Comment: Awesome ...That means there are no values under that ID...its giving you the success message because they are both empty and equal...now ammend your your select statement and put it like this..."SELECT cb_userinputphonecode,cb_phoneverificationcodeFROM t4qcm_comprofiler WHERE id='$myId'"

Comment: the output remains same :- 849Post27New record created successfully27423
null
null
SUCCESS!!! With values - User Input : And Phone Verification :

Comment: That ID has no values for those two columns (cb_userinputphonecode and cb_phoneverificationcode)... for example...do this and you will see that...$query = "SELECT * FROM t4qcm_comprofiler WHERE id='$myId'" ...and then do $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query); and then lastly do print_r(mysql_fetch_array($)) and check the values...done

Comment: $query = "SELECT cb_userinputphonecode,cb_phoneverificationcode FROM t4qcm_comprofiler WHERE id='$myId'";
if ($result = mysqli_query($connect,$query)) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
echo $row['cb_phoneverificationcode'];
} 
var_dump($row['cb_phoneverificationcode']);
var_dump($row['cb_userinputphonecode']);
 if($row['cb_userinputphonecode'] == $row['cb_phoneverificationcode']){ echo "SUCCESS!!! With values - User Input : ".$row['cb_userinputphonecode']." And Phone Verification : ".$row['cb_phoneverificationcode']; }else{ echo "verification code mismatch. Please try again"; }

Comment: i have edited to use musqli_fetch_assoc () instead, also please note in Databse the id field is not null for these 2 colums and when i display the columns / Fileds of cb_userinputphonecode and cb_phoneverificationcode they display the values